# Drop down navigationw works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I've designed a web site with drop down navigation. It seems to work fine in Firefox, But Chrome refuses to show the drop downs on MouseOver.

Might be a JQuery issue....?

URL: http://www.lslib.ca/

**EDIT1**

Problem is being experienced with *Version 45.0.2454.101 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)* (Chromium) and *Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit)* (Chrome on Ubuntu as well)

Comment: Works fine on 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit). Which versions of chrome are you specifically having problems with?

Comment: Works fine for me, too. Even with AdBlock and blocked Trackers. Is there any error-message showing in your console? Any script not loading?

Comment: Yes works fine on Version 46.0.2490.86 m, but  there is error in bootstrap.js, you can see the error in the browser devTools.

Answer (score 0):

It actually appears to work just fine on my end (Chrome & Chromium). The drop downs successfully appear on mouse over. Maybe it's an issue on your browser?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using jQuery 1.4.4 and according to bootsrap (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/bower.json) it needs 1.9.1.

Comment: I installed `https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update` and it upgraded o `1.10` but it still doesn't seem to work for me... is this some kind of "browser on Linux" problem? Weird...

Comment: Now it appears that the problem is with superfish. Try upgrading superfish to the latest version.